# Why doesn't this .htaccess code work?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Was given this code to use and used it without changing it

```
<FilesMatch "^(?!log_request\.php).*$">
  AuthUserFile /protect/.htpasswd
  AuthName "Tester's test test"
  AuthType Basic
  Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 401 /log_request.php
```

I have no idea what the function of the FilesMatch "^(?!log_request.php).*$" line is but other than that the files should match. When i try to view the .htpasswd file i get Internal Server Error.

Comment: Have you checked your logs? Does `/protect/.htpasswd` exist (as an **absolute** path - not a relative one)?

Comment: Yes it should be an absolute path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
<FilesMatch "^(?!.*?log_request\.php).*$">
  AuthUserFile /protect/.htpasswd
  AuthName "Tester's test test"
  AuthType Basic
  Require valid-user
</FilesMatch>

ErrorDocument 401 /log_request.php
```

`(?!...)` is a negative lookahead that makes sure Basic Auth code is applied for all the files except `log_request.php`

#### Option 2 Use `SetEnvIfNoCase`:

```
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI "^/(?!log_request\.php).*" HANDLE401

AuthUserFile /protect/.htpasswd
AuthName "Tester's test test"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
Satisfy    any
Order      allow,deny
Allow from  all
Deny from env=HANDLE401
```

Comment: Whats the change you made and why did you make it? Im trying to actually understand what im seeing. And why is the slash inverted for log_request on the first line?

Comment: change is in the regex: `"^(?!.*?log_request\.php).*$` which makes sure to negate matching `log_request\.php` anywhere in the Request URI. `.*?` is greedy patter to match any arbitrary text before it.

Comment: AH OK, but Im still getting the Internal Server Error. Im trying to access both .htaccess and .htpasswd directly from the website so the directory is correct. Do .htaccess/.htpasswd need specific permissions?

Comment: Just tested, removing the FilesMatch part of the .htaccess changes the message from Internal Service Error to just Forbidden for both .htaccess and .htpassword, but no Authentication is being sent.

Comment: You need to error.log for the actual reason of 500 error. `FilesMatch` works fine and I have tested it. Problem might be in your password file.

Comment: The problem was a messed up location, but the code for FilesMatch still does not work. With FilesMatch on I get internal server error.

Comment: ok with `FilesMatch` present in the .htaccess can you check Apache error.log for the reason of `internal server error`?

Comment: It seems my specific hosting may have banned the use of the FIlesMatch rule...is there any other way to make the script work?

Comment: Ok I will post another option in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use ErrorDocument 401 /log_request.php to send all those requests to some PHP script.
Take a look at this tutorial for more info: http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/htaccess-htpasswd-basic-auth.html